# What is the name of this symbol modifier?

Tags: symbols

I saw the following:

[image]

I thought it might be

```
\bar{\omega}_0^2
```

but it doesn't look the same. The bar on top looks like the top of pi. Is this a unique symbol?

Comment: Maybe `\varpi`  ?

Comment: @Fran That looks to be it!